# Boost::Beast Websocket Bidirection Stream (C++)

Tags: c++, websocket, beast

I'm looking into using the Boost::Beast websocket library to create an asynchronous bidirectional pipe to pass data between a server and a client. I leveraged some code from the async example (I can post some at a later time if necessary, don't have access to it now). I currently have a class which creates several threads running a SocketListener. When a client connects, it creates a Session shared_ptr to do the async read and write functions. The problem is, this session object will only write out when the client has sent me a message. I'm looking for an implementation that allows my server to write on demand to all the clients connected to it and also listen for incoming data from those connections.

Is this possible? Am I using the wrong technique for this? The other way I though this may be achievable is to have an incoming websocket and and outgoing websocket. Incoming would allow a client to drop configurations for the server and outgoing would just monitor a message queue and do a async write if a message is available.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Yes

> Am I using the wrong technique for this?

No

> The other way I though this may be achievable is to have an incoming websocket and and outgoing websocket, and No respectively.

That is not necessary, a websocket stream is full-duplex. You can read and write at the same time.

> outgoing would just monitor a message queue and do a async write if a message is available.

This is the correct approach, but you can do that in the same Session object that also handles the reads.

Here's an example that reads continuously and can also write full-duplex: https://github.com/vinniefalco/CppCon2018

Comment: Hey Vinnie, appreciate the response! I was taking a look at your example and, likely due to my less than expert knowledge of boost::asio, I'm not sure how I would place the server into full duplex once you've upgraded the session to a websocket. The websocket::on_accept is your entrance into the async on_read, which then looks to see if you have messages to send. But that would require the client to send something right? Can we tell the websocket to write without requiring it to read from it first? Thanks again. The library is great :)

Comment: Yes, you can initiate reads and writes independently. The example I linked above does this. You do not "place" the server into full duplex mode, you just issue a reads and writes as needed. It works the same way as a plain socket.

Comment: Thanks. I'm up and running and it seems to be flying and supporting multiple socket connections. The shared state definitely helps facilitate the WS operations. I had to use sync_write instead of async_write though because it seems I was hitting it too quick and they were being called concurrently. Do you see a problem with mixing sync_writes and async_reads?

Comment: You should stick to either synchronous or asynchronous operations. You can only have one call to `async_write` pending at a time. If you want to send the next message before the current message finishes writing, then you must implement your own queue. This is demonstrated here: https://github.com/vinniefalco/CppCon2018/blob/3067248d5488d130fd3caaee2648774e677cea0d/websocket_session.cpp#L109